# What's easier custom .config file or use XML in asp.net

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a situation where I temporarily need to save a bunch of settings to a new website.
Essentially one web service will make the site and it will dump a bunch of data.
I'd rather not store it in the site's app.config.

I could either save all the data as xml or make a file called install.config

Then later on the install wizard can reference it.

**MY question is, what's easier? using XML or reading from a custom config file?**

thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more? I'm not sure what the issue you are trying to resolve is but web.config / install.config etc will also be XML so technically they should be more difficult than each other. The benefit of the .config approach comes when you are setting up external xml files referenced from the original web.config. That then allows you to use the ConfigurationManager to wrap calls to the standard elements of the web.config.

Comment: Hi Brian, when the web service makes the site it needs to save things like webmaster email, site title, paypal email etc.
The database is not yet provisioned so I'd like to save it to an actual file. Then when the user uses the install wizard the file will be referenced. Then later deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aron:

Based on your comments you are simply creating alternative app settings per site. Therefore you can create your web.config as normal but source the appsettings from the external install.config using:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings configSource="install.config" />
</configuration>
```

The benefit of this approach is that you do not need to write any bespoke clases / code to read the values as you can then simply use the usual config calls from your code;

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyInstallSetting"]
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, if I have 3 existing settings in the appSettings can they remain there? Or do I need to move all of them to "install.config"?

Comment: all need to move but I'm assuming they are consistent and can therefore simply be generated inside the install.config?